# Gradient on Sobolev spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose I have a function $\Phi \in L_p(\Omega)$ and $\nabla\Phi \in W^{-\alpha}_p(\Omega)$, $1<p<\infty$ and where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. Can I conclude that $\Phi\in W^{-\alpha+1}_p(\Omega)$ if $\alpha >0$? I have found results for $\alpha=1$ and for $\alpha <0$ (i.e. the gradient is contained in a Sobolev space with positive smoothness parameter).

I would be thankfull for answers!

Comment: Are $a$ and $\alpha$ related ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same :) I've replaced it

Comment: $L^p(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{-\alpha,p}(\Omega)$ for all $\alpha>0$.

Comment: The answer essentially depends on definitions of the spaces you are emlpoying. For $\alpha<0$, your problem is solved
by the Sobolev representation theorem of a weakly differentiable function in terms of its gradient. For $\alpha>0$, it is not the gradient, it is its
conjugate -- the divergence operator that solves your problem, which is much more complicated when homogeneous boundary data is involved.

Comment: The space $W^\alpha(\Omega)$ for negative $\alpha$ is defined as the dual space of $W^{-\alpha,0}_{p'}(\Omega)$ with $1/p+1/p'=1$. So $W^{-\alpha,0}_{p'}(\Omega)$ is the closure of the set of testfunctions with respecht to the Sobolev norm.

Comment: Many thanks mkl314 for your answer. That means if I have no requirements for $\Phi$ concerning the boundary data the statement is true!? But defining the Sobolev space $W^{\alpha}_p$ for negative $\alpha$ as the dual space of $W^{\alpha,0}_{p'}$ means that I have boundary conditions!?

Comment: Duely formulated, it can be made true. In case of homogeneous boundary data, you can't do without the Bogovskii operator which is an explicitly constructed right inverse for the divergence operator with homogeneous boundary data -- for details see Section III.3 of Galdi's book http://bookza.org/book/1224993/332308                          I hope I will write a more detailed comment, or even an answer, maybe in a day or two.